# How to change the object in a vector when I only have a reference to the vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have to calculate the average of the peoples age and than I have to count how many people are younger than average. After that I have to age them up and count how many people are younger than the average again.

```
int magic(Vector<Person>& v, Guild g) {
  if (v.size() == 0) {
    throw runtime_error("");
  }

  int d = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0,
                     [](int sum, Person p) { return sum += p.get_age(); });
  int a = d / v.size();
  auto count =
      count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [a](Person p1) { return p1.get_age() < a; });

  for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [g](Person p) {
    if (p.get_guild() == g) {
      return p.aging();
    }
  });

  auto count2 =
      count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [a](Person p3) { return p3.get_age() < a; });

  return count + count2;
}
```

Comment: `Person p` n your `for_each` lambda is by value. It needs to be by reference, `Person &p`,  if you're changing that object. Aside, consider using `for (auto& p : v)` and belaying the dilapidated `for_each` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambdas are accepting their arguments by value, which means you are making copies of the objects and passing them to the lambdas.

Modifying a copy will not change the original value in the vector.

The solution is to take the arguments by reference.

```
int magic(Vector<Person>& v, Guild g) {
  if (v.size() == 0) {
    throw runtime_error("");
  }

  // taking the Person by const-ref since we don't need to modify it
  int d = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0,
                     [](int sum, const Person& p) { return sum += p.get_age(); });
  int a = d / v.size();
  // again, const-ref
  auto count =
      count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [a](const Person& p1) { return p1.get_age() < a; });

  // Here we take it by reference, so we can modify it.
  // Also capturing the Guild by reference to avoid uneccesary copy
  for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&g](Person& p) {
    if (p.get_guild() == g) {
      return p.aging();
    }
  });

  // again by const-ref
  auto count2 =
      count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [a](const Person& p3) { return p3.get_age() < a; });

  return count + count2;
}
```